# select query to identify numeric or alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table like below:

```
  TN  Tier
  90   1
  90   N3
  30   2
  40   3
  50   A
```

"Tier" column may contain numeric as well as alpha-numeric values for any TN. I want to run a select query on above table so that if for any TN, there are both(numeric and alpha-numeric) values present in Tier column then it should be called as "Mix" otherwise "Numeric" or "Non-Numeric".

Desired Output :

```
 TN   Result
 90    Mix
 30   Numeric
 40   Numeric
 50   Non-Numeric
```

I am able to achieve it by using multiple temp tables but i want to avoid using temp tables. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: For sql server : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07c44/4

Comment: Please tell us whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server, and also why did you tag with two very different databases?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your response... i need to run that query in sql server, it was by mistake. sorry about that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take use advantage of [ISNUMERIC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) function in `SQL Server`.

```
SELECT [TN],
       CASE MAX(ISNUMERIC(Tier)) + MIN(ISNUMERIC(Tier))
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Numeric'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Mix'
            ELSE 'Non-Numeric'
       End As Result
FROM TableName
GROUP BY TN
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6786b/3).

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, use `REGEXP` with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    TN,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Tier REGEXP '[A-Z]' AND Tier REGEXP '[0-9]'
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Mix'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Tier REGEXP '[A-Z]'
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Non-Numeric'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Tier REGEXP '[0-9]'
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Numeric'
         ELSE 'Other' END AS Result
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    TN;
```

For SQL Server, you may slightly alter the above query by using `LIKE` with an appropriate pattern:

```
SELECT
    TN,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Tier LIKE '%[A-Z]%' AND Tier LIKE '%[0-9]%'
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Mix'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Tier LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Non-Numeric'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Tier LIKE '%[0-9]%'
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Numeric'
         ELSE 'Other' END AS Result
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    TN;
```

The SQL Server answer given by @JohnWoo is tighter than this, but as you tagged with MySQL I initially answered for this database.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any big query it can be make with simple,

try this:

```
Select * from table
```

then you can check value of you column in while loop, each time you can search string having number or not number in you record.

```
$string = $row['Tier'];
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $myString) )
{     
   echo 'String contains letters';   
}
else if(preg_match('/[0-9]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'String contains numbers';
}else if($string == '')
{
    echo 'String contains no letter and no number';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you are using mysql. It is better if you can write a custom function as follows.

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION is_numeric(inputValue VARCHAR(50))
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    IF (inputValue REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$'))
    THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END;

Example - select is_numeric(id),is_numeric(full_name) FROM tbl_user;
```